# Yii2, Softdelete, self::tableName(), and ignoring `deleted` records

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, soft-delete

I have a base model class that contains the SoftDelete behavior (`cornernote/yii2-softdelete`). When a record is deleted the column in the table `deleted_at` is populated with a timestamp.

Attempted to override the find() method in the `base` model but self::className() does not return the table prefix with the name.

```
return parent::find()->where([self::tableName() . '.deleted_at' => null]);
```

I have to add it to each model class in order to get the proper (full) table name.

The ask: How best to ignore records in a table that have a column populated. The solution has to work when the model is accessed for ActiveDataProvider([...]), find()->...one(), and find()->...all() situations.

TIA

Comment: You could also use `SoftDeleteQueryBehavior`.

Comment: @soju please elaborate / provide reference.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, and about `SoftDeleteQueryBehavior` take a look at `cornernote/yii2-softdelete` doc

Comment: Weird, I did have the ActiveQuery behavior in my origin classes but did not seem to work. Please be a little more verbose in responses. It feels like the direction is correct but incomplete.

Comment: Make a choice, my answer will solve your original problem. And about SoftDeleteQueryBehavior read carefully the doc and ask another question if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this about **Late Static Bindings** :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

> Late static bindings introduce the `static` keyword that references the class that was initially called at runtime

So, you should simply use **`static::tableName()`** instead of `self::tableName()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Customized Query Class](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#customizing-query-classes)

It is already exist in library, what you are using - [here github](https://github.com/cornernote/yii2-softdelete/blob/master/src/SoftDeleteQueryBehavior.php)

If you want - you can also re-define `find` method.

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to override the base model find() but I have to have the classes table name. tableName() does not return the table prefix and thus the table is not found.

Comment: @Pheagey why do you need table name? can you please share code of your model?